# Updating every record in a collection with a random time?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection where I would like to update a date in every record with a random time in the last few hours.  I have been using the update below:

```
db.users.update(
    {},
    {
        $set: 
        {   
            loggedIn: new Date((ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*(ISODate().getTime()%300)))
        }
    },
    false, 
    true
);
```

But this updates every record with the same random time.  How can I get the `1000*60*(ISODate().getTime()%300` portion to execute with every update instead of executing once and then updating the records with the same value?

Comment: You would have to iterate each record and set it? (Just a guess)

Comment: Is there some reason why this question is still open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right. The operation is atomic and the "random date value" here is being evaluated once, then applied to all records with your `multi` update.

So in whatever programming implementation you want the iterative form:

```
db.users.find({}).foreach(function(user) {

   db.users.update({ _id: user._id },
   {
        $set: 
        {   
            loggedIn: new Date((ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*(ISODate().getTime()%300)))
        }
   });

};
```

There is work on [batch updates](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4004), but even so you would need to generate your "random time" for each document